# How to find out what java compiler was used to compile a random jar

Tags: java, compilation

I made my own java library which uses some external libearies such as `HttpClient` from Apache.

When I compile it and try to use it, I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Even though all dependent libraries are included in my `jar`.

I did some research and it looks like it is an issue with a compiler version. My lib is compiled with `Java 8` while `Apache libs` are compiled with an older version.

My question is, why there isn't any warning about possible issues with such library upon compilation?

And how could I find out with what version of Java was used to compile these libraries?

Comment: I don't think the compiler version is the issue - only when you use an older jvm to run newer code will there be an error (AFAIK). Are you absolutely sure that `org/apache/http/HttpEntity.class` is in your jar? You did unpack the jars before including them, right? Nested jars don't work (except in .war).

Comment: I am not sure about anything now, I just know that when I run my library as a java program, it works fine. However when I bundle it into jar and try to use it in another program, it gives me the exception.

Comment: @Kenney, what do you mean by unpacking jars? They are in my lib folder and they are in a build path, so then they are bundled all in one jar I assume.

Comment: By default, when building a "jar", dependencies from the classpath (libs) are not included into the resulting jar. You need to build a "fat jar" to be able to run the jar as a standalone application, or deliver the libs separately (and add them to the classpath when running the jar).

Comment: I solved it by adding a main class with nothing in it and compiled it as a runnable jar file. So it looks like you were right, dependencies were not part of my compiled jar. I did a way around, but if you have a better solution, feel free to answer my question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are conflating too many things: what compiler, what version of java the compiler compiled the java files into, how use the jar tool, and possibly how to create a manifest file to link to 3rd party jars

Comment: @ControlAltDel yes such questions are sometimes necessary as I wanted to provide as much information as I could and as many assumptions I could come up with. I could also just ask, why am I getting the error. Would it still be off-topic?

Comment: @OndrejTokar Your question itself is not well posed. For starters, you don't compile a jar: You compile classes. For second, you didn't specify whether you were using an external jar referenced in the manifest file, or if you were compiling 3rd party code directly into your java.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what was wrong. I am not using any manifest, I just added a dependency to the build path, in eclipse.